# Normalizing timeInMillis difference for input to progressbar

Tags: java, android

1. T1 : Calendar object created yesterday.
2. T2 : Calendar object created now.
3. T3 : Calendar object created tomorrow.

I want my progress bar to progress as T2 reaches T3. I was casting the long (getTimeInMillis) , dividing , ... finally getting an int. Its not working.
A function like : int CurrentProgressBarValue(Calendar T1, Calendar T2, Calendar T3) { } , would be really helpful right now ! So i'll just set the  maxValue to 100 in the xml and the function will return a proportional integer.

```
    public int getNormalizedProgress(long max, long current){
    double d = (double)current/max;
    d = d * 100;
    Double D = new Double(d);
    return D.intValue();
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code with which you've tried this?

Comment: If you can *guarantee* that T1 and T3 are never more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` milliseconds apart, then you can just subtract T1's time and cast to `int`

Comment: T1 T3 are further apart

Comment: and max , current are difference of getTimeinMillis , taken from a starting point T1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you need to find the number of millis between T1 and T2, and the number of millis between T1 and T3, and then find the ratio.

Since millis is a long, and the difference between T1 and T3 may be larger than an int, you need to do the differences with longs. You need to do the division with doubles so that you can get a decimal result.

Assuming that T1, T2, and T3 are longs, the following will give you a number from 0 to 100 inclusive:

```
(((t2 - t1)*1.0)/((t3 - t1)*1.0) * 100).intValue
```